# 2 Sided Bar Theme Design

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress theme and I want it to have 2 sidebars.
The only way that I find to do that and position these sidebars to be aligned with the content, was puting the primary sidebar on the index page, and the secondary sidebar at the end of the header, I don't know another way to do it.

But now the thing is wherever I put the php Sidebar code in index, somehow the css #footer code it's catching all the page where the sidebars are and the content as well.

The theme -> http://experiencias.freeserver.me/

Here's the code.
I've put colors and border colors to see more clearly what's happening.

**Index code - Primary Sidebar Code is at the bottom of this code:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content" class="filter-posts">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-type="<?php $categories = get_the_category(); $count = count($categories); $i=1; foreach($categories as $category) {    echo str_replace('-', '', $category->slug); if ($i<$count) echo ' '; $i++;} ?>" class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> <?php $categories = get_the_category(); foreach($categories as $category) {  echo str_replace('-', '', $category->slug).' '; } ?>post project">

                <?php 
                    $format = get_post_format();

                    if ($format == 'image') { ?>
                        <img class="post-icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/format-image.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <img class="post-icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/format-standard.jpg" alt="standard" />
                <?php } ?>  

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <!-- uses the post format -->
                        <?php
                            if(!get_post_format()) {
                               get_template_part('format', 'standard');
                            } else {
                               get_template_part('format', get_post_format());
                            };
                        ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bar" <?php if(is_page()) { ?>style="display:none;"<?php } ?>>
                        <div class="bar-frame">
                            <div class="date bar-col">
                                <strong class="day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></strong>
                                <div class="holder">
                                    <span class="month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></span>
                                    <span class="year"><?php the_time('Y'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-scroll"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- post-->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div style="clear:both;"> </div>

            <div class="post-nav">
                <div class="postnav-left"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Page') ?></div>
                <div class="postnav-right"><?php next_posts_link('Next Page &raquo;') ?></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
            </div><!--end post navigation-->

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(is_single ()) { ?>
                <div class="comments">
                    <?php comments_template(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div><!--content-->
    </div><!--main-->

    <div id="sidebar-primary">
    <?php get_sidebar('left'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Header Code - Secondary Sidebar at the bottom of the code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Theme</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<h1>This is the header</h1>
</div>

<div id="sidebar-secondary">
<?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#wrapper {
display: block;
width:92%;
margin:0px auto;
font-family: verdana;
border: 1px #FFFF00 solid;
}

#main {
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:50px;
}

#header {
border: 1px #D9D9D9 solid;
text-align: center;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
#content {
margin-bottom:5px;
overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
margin-left: 275px;
border:#E60000;
}

#sidebar-primary {
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: -890px;
border: 12px #FF3300 solid;
padding:5px;
border-radius:3px;
}
#sidebar-secondary {
overflow: hidden;
float: right;
    width: 320px;
border: 1px #66FF33 solid;
padding:5px;
border-radius:3px;
}
#footer {
background-color:#CCFFCC;
width:100%;
padding:38px 0 0;
font-size:12px;
line-height:18px;
color:#888;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #2a2a2a;
filter: dropshadow(color=#2a2a2a, offx=1, offy=1);
display:block;
}
```

Comment: So where is the CSS code?

Comment: Also, might be best to post the generated HTML instead of the raw PHP so we can diagnose a little better.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the CSS code now and the URL where I'm working on the theme.

Comment: @Chun if it is what I think it is, try adding this code `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` right after `<!--content-->`.

Comment: @Chun or you can try adding this CSS code: `#footer::before {
content: ' ';
display: block;
clear: both;
}`

Comment: Yes it worked. I've put it after the primary sidebar id close tag because before of that the sidebar desapeared, and I just added the second sidebar right after the first one and it seems to be all align in the same wrap now. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all a floating problem really. Since the two sidebars are floating the float needs to be cleared after them so that new content can be added on a new line after them.
To achieve this just add this after the floating elements (in your case right after `<!--content-->`):

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```